# How to merge two shape files or Dfs (one containing centroid locations and other is a region wise shapefile)

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapefile, folium

Want to merge two shapefiles

one is df1

| `Longitude` | `Latitude` |
| --- | --- |
| `-4.096801` | `55.775258` |
| `-2.694467` | `53.725098` |
| `-0.121930` | `51.000306` |
| `-1.837491` | `52.677722` |

Other is df2

| `Region` | `geometry` |
| --- | --- |
| `North East` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((398515.800 653060.200, 398253....` |
| `Scotland` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((512490.996 414654.696, 512679...`. |
| `London` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((479381.800 518245.500, 479975....` |
| `North West` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((357136.203 587050.898, 356572.` |

Expected DF

If the location are located within the region geometry then assign the region to their location like

| `Longitude` | `Latitude` | `Region` | `geometry` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `-4.096801` | `55.775258` | `North East` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((398515.800 653060.200, 398253....` |
| `-2.694467` | `53.725098` | `Scotland` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((512490.996 414654.696, 512679...`. |
| `-0.121930` | `51.000306` | `London` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((479381.800 518245.500, 479975....` |
| `-1.837491` | `52.677722` | `North West` | `MULTIPOLYGON (((357136.203 587050.898, 356572.` |

Unable to merge the two on top of each other.

Comment: What key are you joining the dstaframes on? Row index? If so just use `new_df = df1.join(df2)`

Comment: if the lat long in df1 exists within the geometric boundary of a specific region in df2 on a folium map, they should be merged. 
The union is a overlap on the map.